# How to stop SLF4J loading on Eclipse with NetcdfAll library referenced

Tags: java, eclipse, slf4j, netcdf4

I'm currently developing a Java project on eclipse. At early stages of the project I tried using a logger to log different information, but I finally discarded its usage.

Now, every time I run my application as a "Java Application" it prints this message on the console.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I have tried to close the project and rebuild it and it keeps printing it. Also checked my class imports and buildpath references and there is nothing that seems to be creating the problem there. It's something related to the IDE?

It must also be mentioned that I'm not using dependency managers as maven, and that the unique referenced library I'm currently using is netcdfAll-4.6.jar.

My first thought was obviously it was a problem of dependencies but the problem is that no dependencies can be found on the build path relating to SLF4J.

Comment: remove all dependencies and configuration. this is related to your project, rather than the IDE. Just because you don't use it, doesn't mean it magically disappeared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Maxim Petrusevich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8097748/maxim-petrusevich) pointed in his answer the problem is caused by the netcdfAll-4.6.jar, and the dependency can be seen as he mentioned. More information about this can be found on [NetCDF-Java Build Dependencies](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/netcdf-java/reference/BuildDependencies.html)

As the ussage of the logger is forced by the netcdf library, one possible approach to solve the problem is adding the SLF4J dependencies to the buildpath. For that it is needed to add to the build path the following libraries:

- slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
- log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
- log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.2.jar
- log4j-core-2.10.0.jar

If you follow this solution, a configuration file is going to be needed in order to configure the logger. Some examples can be found [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

Other possible solution that doesn't force you to embrace the usage of the logger is to add to the buildpath the [slf4j-jdk14.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-jdk14) which only weights 8kB. This solution has been found by [MSD Software](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5348077/msd-software), and it has been tested and it works.

Comment: I have an app at the heart of which is the netcdfAll library jar. There's been no need to add the log4j jars, and the slf4j-api code is already zipped into the netcdfAll jar. What I have had to add to the classpath was the slf4j-api jar. Yes, it's an extraneous jar, but it's only 8 kB.

Comment: If I use the approach your approach @msdsoftware , only setting the slf4j-api jar it keeps complaining about the slf4j logger. The message that it returs its the same as in the start of this topic. `SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.`

Comment: Sorry. I mis-typed that. As I said, the slf4j-api code is already zipped into the  netcdfAll jar. What I needed to add to the classpath was **slf4j-jdk14**, which is 8 kB.

Comment: You're right @MSDSoftware it also workswith the solution you mention. I'm going to edit the post with that solution and give credit to you there. Thanks!

Comment: BTW: Once I added the slf4j jars to my build to make netcdfAll happy, I found I started using them. So much more flexible than System.err.println for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like you have SLF4J jar in your project, if you no longer need slf4j, check your maven dependencies (or gradle, or ant) and remove from there sl4j dependency. If you don't use dependency managers, check your project's jars, maybe you have slf4j jar file there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not using dependency managers and I can't find any dependency that is creating the problem. The unique referenced library I'm using is netcdfAll-4.6.11.jar and it has nothing to do with SLF4J.

Comment: @Drubio, well, apparently SLF4J JAR file included in your netcdfAll-4.6.11.jar. You will see that, if you will unpack your jar file and find it at netcdfAll-4.6.11/org/slf4j. I think, you can find all usages of  slf4j library in your project and delete them. It's should help you.

Comment: @Drubio Or, you can go by other way - add slf4j implementation, like slf4j-log4j12 (slf4j-log4j12-1.8.0-beta0.jar e.g.), but because you are don't use logging, it will be superfluous.